# Conformal immersions from surfaces into 3-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, minimal-surfaces

Let $f:(S,g) \to (M,h) $ be a smooth immersion of a compact surface into a 3 - manifold. Is it true that there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi: S \to S$, such that the metric $(f \circ \phi)^*(h)$ is conformal to $g$ ?

To explain the motivation behind ths question, consider first the following set-up. Let $D_2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the standard 2-disk and $f: (S,g_{eukl}) \to (M,g)$ an immersion into a Riemannian manifold. It is well-known that the *area* of $f$ is defined as $A(f) = \int_{D_2} \sqrt{||f_1||_g \cdot ||f_2||_g - g(f_1,f_2)^2 } dx_1dx_2$, where $f_i := \partial f/\partial x_i$. On the other hand, the *Dirichlet energy* is defined as $E(f) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{D_2} ||f_1||_g + ||f_2||_g dx_1dx_2$, and by simply comparing the integrants, one sees that $A(f) \leq E(f)$ with equality holding if and only if $||f_1||_g = ||f_2||_g$ and $g(f_1,f_2) = 0$ everywhere. Immersions with that property are called *conformal* and it is well known that for any given immersion, there exists a parameter transformation $\psi:D_2 \to D_2$ such that $f \circ \psi$ is a conformal immersion. In other words, an immersion $f$ is conformal if and only if $f^*(g) = e^{\phi} \cdot g_{eukl}$ for some smooth function $\phi$ on $D_2$, which means *precisely* that $f^*(g)$ and $g_{eukl}$ are conformal as metrics on $D_2$.

I have some trouble understanding why this is still possible when $f:(S,h) \to (M,g)$ is an immersion of *any* compact Riemannian 2-manifold. I know that the *area* of $f$ is in general defined by $A(g) := \int_S \omega_{f^*(g)}$, whereas the *Dirichlet energy* depends on $h$ and is defined by $E_h(f) := \frac{1}{2} \int_S |df|^2 \omega_h$. I have shown that we always have $A(f) \leq E_h(f)$ (regardless of $h$), where $f$ is said to be *conformal* if equality holds. One can show that this is equivalent to the metrics $f^*(g)$ and $h$ being conformal, i.e $f^*(g) = e^\phi \cdot h$. Is it still true that there exists a diffeomorphism $\psi: S \to S$ such that $f \circ \psi$ is conformal ? I ask because I only find papers that assert the existence of *isothermal coordinates* on any Riemannian 2-manifold, which essentially seems to only imply the case from the first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking whether there is a diffeomorphism $ \psi : S\to S$ so that $f\circ \psi$ is conformal. Writing $g_1 = f^* h$, it's the same as asking whether $ \psi^* g _1$ is conformal to $g$.

Note that $g$, $g_1$ induces two conformal structures on $S$. In general they are not conformal to each other. Indeed, the dimension of the moduli space of conformal structures on a surface of genus $g\ge 2$ is $6g-6$, and is $2$ when $g= 1$.

The only case you can find such a $\psi$ (for a compact surface $S$) is when $S$ is topologically a 2-sphere. This is given by the uniformization theorem, which says that $S$ is conformal to the standard $\mathbb S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

Note that the theorem on the existence of isothermal coordinates can be interpreted as saying that there is only one conformal structure on the unit disk.

Comment: What is your definition of conformal structure ? Because if you are talking about conformal equivalence classes of Riemannian metrics on a fixed surface, it is certainly not true that the unit disk has only one conformal structure. For example, there are immersions of the disk into $\mathbb R^3$ that are not angle preserving, and as such, the corresponding pullback metric cannot be conformally equivalent to the standard eucledian metric on the disk (in the sense that they differ only by a smooth positive scaling function).

Comment: I guess that your definition of conformal structure is that two riemannian surfaces $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are *conformally equivalent* if and only if there exists a diffeomorphism $\phi: M \to N$ such that the metrics $\phi^*(h)$ and $g$ are conformal. I am not too familiar with moduli spaces, but I know that they are mostly introduced as equivalence classes of *complex* structures of surfaces, and the connection between Riemann surfaces and RiemanniAN surfaces is not immediate.

Comment: In dimension 2, conformal structure and complex structure are really the same. So the disc has only one conformal structure, by the uniformization. (given a metric $g$, one can always define an almost complex structure $J$ on the surface by setting $Jv$ to be orthogonal to $v$ and $v, Jv$ are +ve oriented. That this is really a complex structure is proved in sectoni 3.11 in "compact Riemann surfaces" by Jost)